# Drupal 7 meta description in block

Tags: meta-tags

How can i print a node meta description inside a block?

Tried to use tokens but can't figure out the right path...

Comment: no point in doing that, it should be declared inside the head tag

Comment: Are already declared inside the head but i need to show meta description inside a block of the page. Can't understand your comment...

Comment: why do you want to print the meta description tag inside a block ?  meta description must be declared in side the **<head> </head>** tags- so that only search engines will understand.